# Prove that if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x + a) = \infty$ for any $a > 0$.

Tags: limits

***Hypothesis***

Assume that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (d, \infty)$ ($d \in \mathbb{R}$), then $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x + a) = \infty.$$

***Proof***

Since $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty,$$ for any $M > 0$ there exists such an $N$ that $f(x) > M$ when $x > N$. Since $f(x + a) > f(x)$ ($f$ is strictly increasing) for all $x \in (d, \infty)$, for each $M > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $f(x + a) > f(x) > M$ when $x > N$, ans so $$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x + a) = \infty.$$

**Question**

Is this proof correct? If not, how to fix it?

**PS**

(I need this in my MSc thesis in CS while analyzing running times, so, obviously, I am not a professional mathematician.)

Comment: The statement in the title is wrong, $f(x)=x/(x+1)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: coderodde, your proof is wrong, moreover the statement is wrong too, so you need to add another hypothesis if you want the statement to be true.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) $ exists for an increasing function, but that limit need not be $\infty$.

Comment: @MartinR Damn it. I completely forgot to mention two important conditions: (1) $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, and (2) $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (d, \infty), (d \in \mathbb{R}).$

Comment: @Angelo Please see my comment to Martin R.

Comment: To go from $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ to $f(x+a) \rightarrow \infty$ it is "simply" the so called composition of the limits theorem

Comment: @coderodde, if you add the hypothesis $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, it is not necessary that $f’(x)>0$ for all $x\in(d,\infty)$, indeed you can prove the thesis in any case.

Answer (score 1):

The defined about infinity as a limit:
For each real number $M>0$, there exists a number $N$ such that for each $|x|>N$,
$$
 |f(x)|>M,
 $$
As a same process, given any real number $M>0$, there exists a number $N'=N-a$(or $N+a$), each $|x|>N'$, we have
$$
 |f(x+a)|>M.
$$
so $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x+a)=\infty$ .
we don't need $f'(x)$.